# How to insert a record from ROOM into a Home Screen Widget with Clance

Tags: kotlin, android-room, glance

I'd like to insert a record from my ROOM database into a Home Screen Widget. I've added the receiver into the Manifest and created a XML provider. When I run the App and try to add the widget to my home screen I get this error:

```
Error in Glance App Widget                                                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: CompositionLocal LocalView not present
```

This is the code I'm using:

```
class AppWidget() : GlanceAppWidget() {

    @Composable
    override fun Content(){
        val vw = viewModel<NoteViewModel>()
        val lista = vw.noteList.collectAsState().value
        val record = lista.first()

        Row(modifier = GlanceModifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.White).padding(15.dp)) {
            Text(text="${record.titolo}")
        }
    }
}

class AppWidgetReceiver: GlanceAppWidgetReceiver(){

    override val glanceAppWidget: GlanceAppWidget
        get() = AppWidget()


    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        super.onEnabled(context)
        //LocationWorker.enqueue(context)
    }
}
```